# CompletableFuture.isDone blocks CrudRepository.save();

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, java-8, completable-future

I'm trying to store an entity in my database in an async method by returning a CompletableFuture<>. The code works fine as long as I do not check the state of the future (e.g isComplete() or .get()).

```
    CompletableFuture<Product> working = serviceTest.test("working");
```

The above example works, the product is stored in the database.

```
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Product> test(String name)
    {
       Product p = new Product();
       p.setId(new Random().nextInt(500000));
       p.setName(name);
       logger.info("Saving "+ name);
       p = productRepository.save(p);
       logger.info("finished " + name);
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(p);
    }
```

However, as soon as I change the code to for example

```
    CompletableFuture<Product> notWorking = serviceTest.test("notWorking");
    notWorking.get();
```

The entity is not saved and the code freezes at 'productRepository.save(p);'.

What is the correct way to save entities in an async method? Note that this is a simplified example and in the real scenario the test function is a long running operation to fetch a list of products from an external server.
The not explainable issue for me is that a simple method to get the state of the future blocks the saving of my entity.

I extracted a thread dump when the deadlock occurs. This is the relevant part

```
"MigrationTask-1" #19 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbdd4bcd800 nid=0x16ea waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fbda9274000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:187)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000850ab208> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:403)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:66)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineQualifiedTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:363)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.save(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There is a significant difference between `isDone()` and `get()`. The latter is waiting for completion, that’s the intended behavior. Calling `get()` to “check the state of the future” is not the right thing and it’s not clear why you don’t use `isDone()` when you already have shown to know about this method.

Comment: Seems a bit strange that you use @Async annotation. CompletableFuture offers a lot of methods to proceed asynchronously.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard that's the correct way to do it in Spring. You let Spring handle the asynchronous execution, in particular the selection of the executor. Also, that's easier to write than with lambda's or method references.

Comment: @Thieeu Did you try to extract a thread dump when you get the "freeze"?

Comment: I just added a thread dump to the question

Comment: @Thieeu Did you find a solution for your question?